# Python requests.get returning ValueError when looping over URLs

Tags: python, csv, http, python-requests

I'm writing a script to do the following:

1. Ingest a csv file
2. Loop through values in a url column
3. Return status codes for each url field

My data is coming from a csv file that I've written. The url field contains a string with 1 or 2 urls to check.

The CSV file is structured as follows:

```
id,site_id,url_check,js_pixel_json
12187,333304,"[""http://www.google.com"", ""http://www.facebook.com""]",[]
12187,333304,"[""http://www.google.com""]",[]
```

I have a function that loops through every column correctly however when it I attempt to pull the status code, I'm getting a

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "help.py", line 29, in <module>
    loopUrl(inputReader)
  File "help.py", line 26, in loopUrl
    urlStatus = requests.get(url)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 72, in get
    return request('get', url, params=params, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 58, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 498, in request
    prep = self.prepare_request(req)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 441, in prepare_request
    hooks=merge_hooks(request.hooks, self.hooks),
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/models.py", line 309, in prepare
    self.prepare_url(url, params)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/models.py", line 375, in prepare_url
    scheme, auth, host, port, path, query, fragment = parse_url(url)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/util/url.py", line 185, in parse_url
    host, url = url.split(']', 1)
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)
```

Here is my code:

```
import requests 
import csv 

input = open('stackoverflow_help.csv')
inputReader = csv.reader(input)


def loopUrl(inputReader):
    pixelCheck = []
    for row in inputReader:
        checkUrl = row[2]
        if inputReader.line_num == 1:
            continue #skip first row
        elif checkUrl == '[]':
            continue
        elif checkUrl == 'NULL':
            continue
        urlList = str(checkUrl)
        for url in urlList:
            urlStatus = requests.get(url)
        print(urlStatus.response_code)

loopUrl(inputReader)
```

The issue traces back to the module and I believe something is happening with the loop which is causing the error.

Comment: post the traceback if the error as well

Comment: What's `response_code`? Please post your actual code.

Comment: I take it that he means `.status_code`? (Like he uses in `getStatus()`).

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "help.py", line 29, in <module>
    loopUrl(inputReader)
  File "help.py", line 26, in loopUrl
    urlStatus = requests.get(url)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 72, in get
    return request('get', url, params=params, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 58, in request

Comment: return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 498, in request
    prep = self.prepare_request(req)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 441, in prepare_request
    hooks=merge_hooks(request.hooks, self.hooks),
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/models.py", line 309, in prepare
    self.prepare_url(url, params)

Comment: File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/models.py", line 375, in prepare_url
    scheme, auth, host, port, path, query, fragment = parse_url(url)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/util/url.py", line 185, in parse_url
    host, url = url.split(']', 1)
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)

Comment: Updated with the full error I'm getting. I'm having trouble figuring out what the other value it's expecting...

Comment: updated the post with error details

Comment: You are trying to iterate a string, not a list

Comment: You're converting the string `"[""http://www.google.com"", ""http://www.facebook.com""]"` to another string via `urlList = str(checkUrl)`, then you proceed to iterate over that string. The URL object then tries to fetch the url `'['`, `'""`, etc.

Answer (score 1):

["http://www.google.com", "http://www.facebook.com"] is a string, not a list. You are iterating it character by character, thus giving you the error above.
You need to do a safe evaluation of the list to get the list of URLs instead of strings.

Example:

```
>>> import ast
>>> x = u'[ "A","B","C" , " D"]'
>>> x = ast.literal_eval(x)
>>> x
['A', 'B', 'C', ' D']
>>> x = [n.strip() for n in x]
>>> x
['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']
```

Reference: [Convert string representation of list to list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1894269/convert-string-representation-of-list-to-list)

In your code it would be:

```
    urlList = ast.literal_eval(checkUrl) # not str(checkUrl)
    for url in urlList:
        urlStatus = requests.get(url)
    print(urlStatus.response_code)
```

Answer (score 0):

Need to clean this up a bit, but should get you going:

```
import requests 
import csv 
import ast


input = open('stackoverflow_help.csv')
inputReader = csv.reader(input)


def loopUrl(inputReader):
    pixelCheck = []
    for row in inputReader:
        if inputReader.line_num == 1:
            continue #skip first row

        checkUrl = row[2]
        try:
            checkUrl = ast.literal_eval(checkUrl)
        except:
            continue


        if checkUrl == []:
            continue
        elif checkUrl == 'NULL':
            continue

        for url in checkUrl:
            urlStatus = requests.get(url)
            print(urlStatus.status_code)

loopUrl(inputReader)
```

**Output:**

```
200
200
200
```